# Get logs of all update queries within database in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am looking to get all the update statements with old and new values within a database into one table.
For an example :
I have database name `"users".`
It contains four tables `"primary_info","address_info","avtars","audit_logs"`

Now, Whichever update statements executes on `primary_info`,`address_info` and `avtars` table that i need to log into audit logs table with below way.

```
ID, Table Name, Field_name,Old_value,New_value,Current Datetime
```

I know we can create triggers to manage such things.But i have database which contains more than 90 tables.So it won't help me to achieve by making trigger (update before) .

So is there any other way which i missed here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Triggers only. All another methods needs in special conditions and are too expensive. *i have database which contains more than 90 tables.So it won't help me to achieve by making trigger* What is the relation?

Comment: @Akina thanks for answer. I mean it's not good to create 90 triggers to achieve a simple thing.If there is table increase each time trigger also needs to be added .So instead of this solution i was looking for better alternative.

Comment: @Akina thanks for answer. I mean it's not good to create 90 triggers to achieve a simple thing.If there is table increase each time trigger also needs to be added .So instead of this solution i was looking for better alternative.

Comment: *I mean it's not good to create 90 triggers to achieve a simple thing.* ?? This is not a problem. You have another problem - even if you'll use triggers they won't log cascade operations. *looking for better alternative.* Do not use queries, move all your logic into stored procedures which will perform both needed actions and logging.